# How can I import browser module in next.js without dynamic import

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, monaco-editor, dynamic-import

```
 import Highlighter from "monaco-jsx-highlighter";
```

this import in next.js gives "document not found" error. So i tried to dynamically import

```
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
const Highlighter = dynamic(import("monaco-jsx-highlighter"), { ssr: false });
```

However dynamic import returns Loadable Component. I checked the next-github and looks like dynamic import works only for components. But `import Highlighter from "monaco-jsx-highlighter"`. Highlighter is actually a class and needs to be initialized as :

```
const highlighter = new Highlighter()
```

How can I use this module in next.js without dynamic import?

Comment: What is `document not found` error? Could you post it here?

Comment: Server Error

ReferenceError: document is not defined
This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Call Stack
insertStyleElement
file:/home/tesla/Documents/projects/portfolio/client/node_modules/monaco-jsx-highlighter/dist/webpack:/monaco-jsx-highlighter/node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/injectStylesIntoStyleTag.js (93:15)

Comment: @Danila since there is a pending edit, I cannot edit the question.

Comment: Seems like the problem is that highlighter is client side only component and cannot run on server with SSR. You could import it regularly into some other component, like `HighlighterWrapper` and then import `HighlighterWrapper` dynamically into your main component where you need it, it should work.

Comment: @Danila Highlighter is a class . How can I import it in HighlighterWrapper?

Comment: Like you always do, `import Highlighter from "monaco-jsx-highlighter";`

Comment: @Danila If I did not misunderstood you I created a ts file. `import Highlighter from "monaco-jsx-highlighter";
export default Highlighter;
`  then I dynamically import it to he file but i still got a Loadable Component

Comment: Yes, you misunderstood, I'll make an answer

Answer (score 3):

Seems like the problem is that highlighter has client side only code and cannot run on server with SSR. You could import it regularly into some other component, like `HighlighterWrapper` and then import `HighlighterWrapper` dynamically into your main component where you need it, then it should work.

```
import Highlighter from "monaco-jsx-highlighter";

export const HighligherWrapper = (props) => {
  // Make instance here or outside
  const highlighter = useMemo(() => new Highlighter(),[]);  

  // Do whatever you want here with highlighter instance

  return <div>Something</div>;
}

export default HighligherWrapper;
```

```
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";

const HighligherWrapper = dynamic(()=> import("./HighligherWrapper"), { ssr: false });

const Page() {
  // Now you can use it in your code and it won't break SSR
  return (
    <div>
      <HighligherWrapper />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try smt. like this:

`/ClientSideComponent.js`:

```
import Highlighter from "monaco-jsx-highlighter";

export default function ClientSideComponent(props){
    // Write here the Highlighter logic.
    return <Highlighter />;
}
```

`/page.js`:

```
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
const ClientSideComponent = dynamic(()=> import("./ClientSideComponent.js"), { ssr: false });

function Page(props) {
    return <ClientSideComponent />
}
```

Comment: What that means?

Comment: @Peter that means, the module that you import should be a component. But in this case Highlighter is a class, so dynamic import does not work

Comment: Then create a standalone `Component`, write the business logic how should the Highlighter work, and import that `Component` `dynamicly` to the current page.

Comment: Sec, Im updating my answer

Comment: @Yilmaz I have updated my answer, and also check out, how `dynamic(()=> import(), {})` works

Comment: @Peter Thank you for your answer.  I upvoted both answers :) However I still have an issue and currently cannot update the question due to a pending edit. it is 5am here and I will hopefully be able to update the question when I wake up

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue with the vanilla dynamic import instead of next.js dynamic import.

```
let jsxHighlighter = null;
import("monaco-jsx-highlighter").then((allMonacoSyntaxHighlighter) => {
  jsxHighlighter = allMonacoSyntaxHighlighter.default;
});
```